# code keeps on returning to a submit button for some reason

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os, time, smtplib

top = tk.Tk()
top.withdraw()

def pause(n):
    time.sleep(n)

def clear():
    os.system('cls')

def valueGET(val1, val2):
    top.withdraw()

    user = val1 + "@gmail.com"
    pswd = val2

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user, pswd)
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print "Sorry, wrong password and/or username"
        pause(1)
        clear()
        login()
    print "sucess"

def login():
    top.deiconify()

    L1 = tk.Label(top, text="User Name")
    L1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    E1 = tk.Entry(top, bd = 5)
    E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    L1 = tk.Label(top, text="Password")
    L1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    E2 = tk.Entry(top, bd = 5, show="*")
    E2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    submit = tk.Button(top, text="Submit", width=15, command=lambda: valueGET(E1.get(), E2.get()))
    submit.grid(row=3, column=1)

    top.mainloop()

def main():
    print "Do you wish to proceed?"
    cont = raw_input("> ").lower()

    if cont[0] == "y":
        clear()
        login()
        print "pass"


main()
```

pardon me for not describing the question accurately enough but I honestly cant think of another way of putting it. When I run the code it goes all the way through to valueGET() and if the user and pass is correct it should (i think break out of the try block - which it does because i put a basic print statement to test that. But then it goes straight to the login again and stops at the submit button (i ran it through visual studio to see where it was getting stuck and it looks like its there). SO anyways, if anyone could help clarify this it would be great... much thanks in advance

Comment: Is `valueGET()` supposed to `return` any value?

Comment: not that I know of, should it? all its supposed to do is log the person into their gmail account, and then proceed to the rest of the main()

Comment: you shouldn't run `login()` in `except` - it creates recursion - and code returns to window without `login()`. Frankly, it never leave this window. After correct login you should close window with `top.destroy()`

Comment: This _does work_ exactly how I expect it to work. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: I think you should put only `top.deiconify()` as `login` and then call `top.destroy()` if the user validates. In its current state it keeps, at best, overwriting widget objects and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems. If I understand you right, you get into the `except` block and from there you call login() again. However you did not clear your `top` window. Should the window contain the login form twice? And you call the `top.mainloop()` in `login()` which causes the mainloop to be run a second time when you call `login()` the second time.

Try moving `top.mainloop()` outside `login()` (maybe into the `main()` function and do not recreate the contents of your window.